# STM32 Discovery Embedded Serial bootloader USART, IAP

Tags: c, in-app-purchase, stm32, stm32ldiscovery

I have a serious issue, I want to boot my stm32 discovery board (STM32L152RBT6) using usart. I have tried going into system memory boot mode by putting BOOT0=HIGH and BOOT1=LOW. Then i tried to send my .BIN file using hyperterminal (Nothing happens). I also tried Flash loader utility by ST(It hangs on detecting the target).

I also read some data sheets about In Application Programming. I downloaded the IAP firmware, and burnt it, but nothing appears on hyperterminal maybe because usart might have some different configurations set on it.

I just want to program my flash memory of stm32 discovery board using usart. Please help!
After i boot into system memory ,whats next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download "STMicroelectronics Flash Loader" supposedly this is the software used for programming using USART -I think so- but I wasn't lucky enough as it couldn't connect to my custom board

Comment: Yes thanx, i downloaded the latest ver. 2.5 of stmicroelectronics flash loader which supported stm32l1xxx. It boots ok now.

Answer (score 1):

I think it only accepts comports 0-9 even though it lets you select >10, using device manager set your comport to <10 and try it again :)

I had the exact same problem and it was because i was trying to use a comport >9 :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi i haven't worked on stm32. but if worked with flash bootloader software provided by ST.
Please enable the bootloader option byte.
Then reset the microcontroller and immediately you have to click on the next.
It will work.

In my st controller, It search the location 8000 for 0x82 or 0xAC byte. 
If you clear the location 8000. then it will remain in bootloader only.
Then you can test the flash loader software it will work.